# Deserialize a JavaScript object as Dictionary<string, string> via ModelBinding in Web API

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have a simple `JavaScript` string and object:

```
var name = "Scarlett Johansson";
var args = { arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar" };
```

And I want to pass them via `$.ajax` to a Web API controller:

```
public string Get([FromUri]TestClass input) {
    // would like Args model-bound 
}
```

And my TestClass is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Args { get; set; }
}
```

The Name property is bound as expected, but I haven't found a way to bind **Args**. I've tried `JSON.stringify(args)`, `$.param(args)`, using a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` on `TestClass` instead of `Dictionary`, nothing has worked.

I was hoping I could achieve this via model binding instead of manually de-serializing the JSON. Is this possible?

**Clarification**: the number of keys/values would vary in "args" from call to call, hence my need for a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's extend your method with implementation (to see the result of what we've passed) like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]TestClass input)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<TestClass>(HttpStatusCode.OK, input);
}
```

And if we would like to see this:

```
{
 "Name":"MyName",
 "Args":
  {
   "FirstKey":"FirstValue",
   "SecondKey":"SecondValue"
  }
}
```

Other words the `testClass.Name == "MyName"` and `testClass.Args["FirstKey"] == "FirstValue"`... we can call the API like this:

```
api/MyService/?name=MyName&args[0].key=FirstKey&args[0].value=FirstValue&args[1].key=SecondKey&args[1].value=SecondValue
```

The params on separated lines, just for clarity (*URI will be without line breaks!)*:

```
api/MyService/
  ?name=MyName
  &args[0].key=FirstKey
  &args[0].value=FirstValue
  &args[1].key=SecondKey
  &args[1].value=SecondValue
```

Comment: Ah, I see, so I'll just need to write a little function that iterates through the JS object's properties and appends that format to the URI with indices included. Seems doable. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

the default model binding wont work like that, it attempts to bind to public properties on objects.  in this example, you would need a class containing like :

```
public class ArgClass
{
    public string Arg1 { get; set; }
    public string Arg2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ArgClass> Args { get; set; }
}
```

the alternative, which seems like you would want to do, is write a custom model binder, or a quick google search turns up this DefaultDictionaryBinder someone seems to have implemented already

https://github.com/loune/MVCStuff/blob/master/Extensions/DefaultDictionaryBinder.cs

**Update**:  just realized you are using web api, which is i guess slightly different.  Here's a blog post explaining how the binding works for web api: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that my "args" object would have varying number of properties, hence my need for a Dictionary on the other side. I'll update my question.